# Can Ubuntu be used to set-up BigblueButton?

Tags: configuration

Can Ubuntu be used to set-up BigblueButton? If so, can I get details on cost and details of services provided?

Answer (score 1):

It could. You can find detailed setup instructions for BigBlueButton on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit server, here:

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html